# Stop inotifywait instance

Tags: inotify

I made a script to invoke `inotifywait`.
It works fine, but I sometimes want to stop it.

How do I stop the last `inotifywait` instance?

I cannot understand how to use `inotify_rm_watch` which I understand is used to close it.

```
7341 ?        S      0:00 inotifywait -m /home/andy/Downloads/ --format %w
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inotify_rm_watch` you refer to is the API (C-function) you would use when writing a "real" program (in C or something similar), not a script. So it doesn't apply to your situation.

If you want to stop `inotifywait` you can do it as with any other program:

- Either issue `ps -ef | grep inotifywait`, pick the PID (in your example presumably `7341`) and then send it a signal:

  `kill 7341`
- Or use the *convenience script* `killall` which kills *all* programs with a given name. `killall` is usually installed by default.

  `killall inotifywait`

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question was in response to a need to find files that I have created. Sometimes I forget where I save them. I would like something that could find files created withing the last 5 minutes. What do you think of this ?                                    find  /home/andy/Downloads -iname "*.png" -mmin -5 -print

Comment: @fixit7 AU has means to express gratitude. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) But don't hurry, take your time. /// Your `find` looks good, but actually it is a completely new question that has nothing to do with `inotifywait`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8347359/5830574), for example, for a similar question on [so].

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I didn't want to push you. You can always change your mind when a better answer appears tomorrow or next month. I just wanted to say that accepting and/or up (or down)voting is the way to say "Thank you" here.

Comment: I don't feel pushed. Hope you have a great day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WHEN USING `kill <pid>`?**

You might have more than one `inotifywait` processes because other scripts can use `inotifywait` independently. So using this command `ps -ef | grep inotifywait` to find the right PID is not the best thing to do because you need to have **a good assumption** which `inotifywait` process belongs to your script. So, you might end up killing the wrong PID. Besides, the command `killall inotifywait` is more aggressive than the previous one. However, if you really don't care other system is using inotifywait, you use the aggressive command.

**MY BEST WAY TO KILL `inotifywait` PROCESS FOR EACH `inotifywait` instance**

You can create a file flag to terminate inotifywait for a specific running script. Below scripts is example how you start the inotify script, stop it, or even test if it's running for that specific inotify PID.

```
#!/bin/bash
# inotify-test.sh
test="changes.txt" # Monitoring file
flag="flag.txt" # For stopping, starting event or whatever flag you need
REPORT_FILE="report.txt"
cat /dev/null > $REPORT_FILE
pid="inotify-test.pid"
cat /dev/null > $max_pid
ARGS1="$1"

function start_monitor {

# If file not exist, then write default start
if [ -f "${flag}" ]; then
        echo "start" > "${flag}"
fi
# Do not use -q -q (twice), because it will not output anything after do while loop
(echo "$BASHPID" > $pid; exec inotifywait -q $flag $test -e modify -m) |
while read file action
do
        process_flag=$(head -1 ${flag})
        if [ "${process_flag}" == "stop" ]; then
                echo "Process stopped" >> $REPORT_FILE
                kill -- -$$
        elif [ "${process_flag}" == "sleep" ]; then
                echo "Process sleep: $$" >> $REPORT_FILE
                sleep 5
                # Important, after sleep, must write start to start
                echo "start" > "${flag}"
        elif [ "${process_flag}" == "start" ]; then
                echo "Process is running" >> $REPORT_FILE
                # Only run here if flag is start
                echo "File: $file, action: $action, date `date`" >> $REPORT_FILE
        else
                echo "Invalid flag $$" >> $REPORT_FILE
        fi
done & # This symbol & is important, it will run this inotify in background

}

if [ "${ARGS1}" == "start" ]; then
        start_monitor
fi

if [ "${ARGS1}" == "stop" ]; then
        echo "stop" > "${flag}"
fi

if [ "${ARGS1}" == "test" ]; then
        echo "sleep" > "${flag}"
fi
```

You can watch this action from the log file `$REPORT_FILE`

```
tail -f report.txt
```

To start monitoring, you can use:

```
./inotify-test.sh start
```

To test the script with if inotifywait is running you do this command:

```
./inotify-test.sh test
```

So, to stop the inotify running process, you just need to run the same script with

```
./inotify-test.sh stop
```

With this method, you don't need to know what is the process ID for that inotifywait process.

**HOW DOES IT WORK?**

You notice that I have 2 files to monitor `$flag $test` from the `inotifywait` command so if I make changes to the `$flag` file, the modify even will be triggered immediately and I can use this opportunity to stop the PID process inside the `inotifywait loop`. Also, you can see that the script actually stores an actual pid of `inotifywait` at `pid="inotify-test.pid"`. So you can manually terminate the `inotifywait` process using this correct pid.

Answer (score 0):

This kills all the instances of `inotifywait`:

```
pkill inotifywait
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `inotifywait --daemon` you never get the process's ID.

If you're like me and don't want to kill ALL the instances of inotifywait indiscriminately you can instead use `nohup` and `inotifywait --monitor`.

Here's how I'm using it in my bash scripts. It allows me to not disturb other running instances of `inotifywait`:

```
# Launch with nohup and redirect inputs and outputs
nohup inotifywait --monitor --outfile /out/file </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &

# Gets process ID of last launched process.
_INOTIFYWAIT_PID=$!

# later on ...

# Kill only this instance of 'inotifywait'
kill ${_INOTIFYWAIT_PID}
```

The input and output redirection commands (`</dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`) comes from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901687/12343158)